# Creating an app for a forum/website in corona sdk

Tags: lua, coronasdk

There is a forum that I like to use, and I would like to make an app for using the forum on iPhone and so on.
I have made a few apps, but never with any websites integrated, so I wonder:
Can I make an app for the forum, and make it look nice? Would I have to ask the forum owner for API or can I just do it?

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to know what HTTP GET, POST, etc calls to make. If the forum is a web app built by owner using custom code, then yes easiest is to ask owner. If REST API for forum, then you'll probably only need the top level API and can discover the rest (sorry for pun not intended). If forum is off-the-shelf ilke django or joomla or phpBB or such, then the API is available to you on those app documentation site.